# How to go about implementing Git/GitLab to your website to enable people to work on code?

Tags: java, git, github, version-control, gitlab

I'm trying to create a project where, i'll have a list of selectable files on my website/command line interface and then the user can select the file (which will be say java code) and then they can essentially download it/fork it? then upload their modified version after(push)

Im not asking for code but a rough outline and guidance of the steps I should take to create this (not the website itself) just what I should use to create this kind of system, is gitlab suitable?

Would just like some help in getting pushed into the right direction, very new to building these kind of systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets make some things clear:

- Git is commonly referred to as the command line program that you use to commit, push, diff etc. This is a tool you need to install locally on any computer that uses Git.
- Git also has a [server application](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server). This is an application you will need to "host" a Git repository. When you have this installed people can `git clone [your-server-and-repository-here]` like you describe.

However, if you want to user interface to the server, Git does not provide this by default. [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) is a open source project that reads the information provided by Git running on your server. It manages permissions, creation of repositories, issues, commit history and everything else.

In short, GitLab does just what you describe. You can use it as your local GitHub and it is free. However, you should be aware that setting it up is not that easy and may take some time. There are a few tutorials and some getting started articles out there. I'd recommend looking at them and ask a new question if you have something more concrete you need help with.

Comment: Sorry, but could you perhaps link me to any related articles? Im having trouble getting my head around it so I only have a vague idea on what to research, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are running Windows or Linux, but I used the Digital Ocean tutorial to set it up for Linux a while back. It takes some time, but if you follow the steps carefully it should not be a problem. The article is here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: this is perfect! I should of mentioned we were going to do it on ubuntu, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab is based on ruby, Since you have a tag "java", I think here is a better example: https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket

Additionally, you just need to have a version control for your texts, I think you just need to use part of there code.

---

If you just wanna to deploy a site like gitlab, you can just follow its official guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html#consider-the-omnibus-package-installation